XSLT count values in array
I have an array in one XML node like this

<Array>1, 2, 3</Array>


How do I count the number of values (in this case 3) in this array using XSLT ?
I can find a lot of articles where the values are placed in separate XML nodes like this

<Array>1</Array>
<Array>2</Array>
<Array>3</Array>


, but this does not apply to my problem.
I have tried figuring it out myself, without any luck.

In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153). If it is version 1.0 (or 1.1), also tell us which processor it is, so that we know if there are any extension functions that could be useful (as in this case).

Also, it helps you and everyone else using Google if you learn the correct terminology. This is not an array. XSLT, from version 3.0, does have arrays, and they are something quite different.

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can use:
<xsl:value-of select="count(tokenize(Array, ', '))"/>


In XSLT 1.0, without any extension function, you could count how many comma characters there are and add one:
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(translate(Array, translate(Array, ',', ''), '')) + 1"/>

However, this hack relies on the comma character being used exclusively as the delimiter or inside the delimiter pattern. It cannot be used with an input such as:
<input>one+++two+++three+++four+half+++five+++six</input>

where the pattern "+++" serves as the delimiter between the tokens, but "four+half" is a legitimate single token. In such case it is necessary to call a named recursive template to count the tokens - for example:
<xsl:template name="count-tokens">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
    <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="count-tokens">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

Again, this is assuming the processor does not support tokenizing as an extension function, such as EXSLT str:split().
